# Deja dup not working in 20.04

Tags: backup, 20.04, python3, deja-dup

I'm trying to create a backup using deja dup backup tool. When I click Bakcup now... I'm getting the message:

> In order to continue the following packages need to be installed:
>   python3-pydrive

I've tried searching for a tutorial in how to do this, and found one on linuxsize

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-20.04/

This suggests that it's better to install python 3 from apt unless you are installing to a virtual environment, in which case pip install is appropriate.

What is the best way to install python3-pydrive on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Why not just `sudo apt install python3-pydrive`  (ie. get the package designed to be used for focal/20.04 unless you've mangled your sources).  As I read your text, it's what the article suggested anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Thanks @guiverc, I think that's what I needed. I don't know terminal command well enough to do that own.

Comment: @NOrbert, I have Universe repository enabled, I prob could have looked in the Package manager, but am trying to learn the terminal commands. thanks.

Comment: FYI:  try `apt-cache policy python3-pydrive`  .. it'll tell you if you've any package name installed, plus in my case what package(s) are available (and from where) with that name...  (or if package name isn't completely known, or just because -- try `apt-cache search pydrive` (which should find any packages with pydrive in the name letting you narrow down needed package, see what is available etc)...

Comment: I realise now that I had enabled Google-drive as a backup method. This is why deja dup was asking for python3-pydrive.